# why is file_get_contents not working with html files?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an editor.php page that gets a file name from different page and loads it into a codemirror editor. My problem is that it only works with .txt files but doesn't work with .html or .java files.

```
<?php
    $login=$_COOKIE['login'];
    $directory = "userFiles/" . $login . "/";
    $filename = isset($_POST['files']) ? $_POST['files'] : false;
    $content = @file_get_contents($directory.$filename);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Editor</title>
<script src='codemirror/lib/codemirror.js'></script>
<script src='codemirror/mode/css/css.js'></script>
<script src='codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'>
<style>
.CodeMirror {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="code" name="code" autofocus></textarea>
<button class="button" id="save">Save</button>
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    mode: 'text/html',
    tabMode: 'indent',
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    autoCloseTags: true
});
editor.setValue("<?php echo $content;?>"+);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Leaving alone the `+` in `setValue`, this should not work with anything that is larger than one line, since JavaScript disallows multi-line strings. It will definitely fail with anything with a quote in it, since it will form invalid JavaScript. Use `editor.setValue(<?php echo json_encode($content); ?>");` to properly create a string you can pass on to JavaScript.

Comment: You should validate the requested file, otherwise one can read any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that such files have a lot of double quotes (`"`). Now what happens with

```
"<?php echo $content;?>"
```

indeed: you get strings like `"<a href="google.com">link</a>"`. JavaScript tries to interpret these, but can't understand that all of a sudden you stop the string, after all JavaScript sees:

```
"<a href="google.com">link</a>"
^        ^  ^
|        |  \-- something weird??!
|        \--end string
\--start string
```

I suggest you look to the raw source code of the generated page to check this.

**Solution?**

You can solve this as @Amadan suggests, by using a carrier like for instance JSON. By `json_encode`, you encode the string in a format, JavaScript can undestand. You could also use a different format (where you escape the quotes), but in that case, JavaScript will need to do some decoding for which it is not designed (you then thus need to write a decoding algorithm).